# JS can't read image width

Tags: javascript, properties, element

I'm doing basic exercises for students in JS and one of them requires to change the image size like 50% and back on button click.

I use the following HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img id="image" src="krogan.png" alt="krogan">
            <input type="button" value="Change size">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

with following CSS

```
button {
    display: block;
}

img {
    display: block;
    width: 256px;
    height: 256px;
}
```

and when I try to get current image width using this JS code

```
window.onload=function() {
    alert(document.getElementById('image').style.width);
}
```

I get an empty message instead of actually set width. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there is no `style` property on that img tag ... - did you want to *get* the *Computed*  CSS *Style* width, or the actual *natural Image Width*?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following:-

```
alert(document.getElementById("image").offsetWidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the CSS width, these are not set.

What you want is the real width, you can get it from the `clientWidth` property:

```js
document.getElementById("image").clientWidth;
```

Same works for `clientHeight`.

The client width or height are the real sizes that are being displayed by the browser to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you assign the width using JavaScript and remove it from the CSS file. Then you can manipulate it in JavaScript like this:

```
document.getElementById('image').css('width') == '256px';
```